# Sharepoint 2010 - web analytics results limit

Tags: 2010, web-analytics

Is there a way of getting Central Administration web analytics to return more than 2000 results? This appears to be the default maximum.

I need a list of all users and their associated page views since date X, but we have nearly 3000 users - is there a way of either increasing the number of results the analytics will return, using PowerShell to return a more complete list, or querying the database directly?

Many thanks in advance for your thoughts.